# Start a workflow from the ECB

Tags: workflow, custom-actions, ecb-menu

I want to add a custom action to the ECB to start a workflow automatically.
To get to the workflow page I can do something like:

```
<UrlAction Url="/_layouts/Workflow.aspx?ID={ItemId}&amp;List={ListId}"/>
```

I can’t work out how to start a workflow automatically rather than go to the workflow page.

What is the syntax that I would need?